# Populate a field on node creation

Tags: 7

I have a content type "abc". I have a field "listing id". I want this field to be prepopulate starting from  1 and autoincrement" on every "abc" node creation.

How can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you can use the [Serial Field](http://drupal.org/project/serial) module to accomplish this.

From the Serial Field page on Drupal.org:

> **Usage**
>
> You can add a serial field to any type at admin/content/types ->
>   manage fields. In the New Field form select Serial as the type of data
>   and label and field name as your choice, and Save. No other settings.